# MySQL get dates that have records but are missing a specific record

Tags: mysql

Hopefully the title isn't too vague, but I'll explain. I'm pretty new to advanced queries so unfortunately this is not as much of a "i'm trying this" as much as a "how would I even go about doing this" type of question.

I have a table of user activity. When they do something on the site, it gets entered into this database. Unfortunately there was a change in how logging-in was tracked. So now I need to find all records for each user id, check the date for each record and see if there is a record with a specific id for that date.

I realize that sounds confusing so I will break it down into the best programming logic I can

1. get list of records for user_id order by date
2. for each date, check if id 5 exists
3. if id 5 doesn't exist, tell me about

Basically I will be inserting that id into the table where that id doesn't exist based on that date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit**
I forgot to add a basic structure here.

```
id      | user_id      | item_id     | stamp
------------------------------------------------------
1       | user1        | 1           | 2012-08-25
2       | user1        | 2           | 2012-08-25
3       | user1        | 3           | 2012-08-25
4       | user1        | 4           | 2012-08-25
5       | user1        | 6           | 2012-08-25
6       | user1        | 7           | 2012-08-25
7       | user1        | 5           | 2012-08-26
8       | user1        | 11          | 2012-08-26
9       | user1        | 13          | 2012-08-26
```

So that's the basic structure. User1 is missing id 5 on `2012-08-25` so I would need to add it in with that date. user1 is not missing id 5 on `2012-08-26` so I would not need to insert anything at all. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: SQLFiddle or at least some structure info would be very useful.

Comment: I'm pretty much just running the queries in phpma. I'm sure there are better ways. I don't even know what sqlfiddle is (I will after typing this though.)

Comment: ...i think i need a lesson in formatting my posts so that the tables look like..tables. I typed it out clean, but it looks like it reformatted the text.

Comment: I think you have a typo. The row where `item_id` is `5` has a different month to all the other rows.

Comment: @theon you were correct, that was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   user_id, stamp
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY user_id, stamp
HAVING   NOT SUM(item_id=5)
```

Here is a working SQLFiddle example with your sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ccf5/5

Comment: Beat me to it :) I've added the SQL fiddle example I was going to post (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ccf5/5).

Comment: What this seems to do is give me every record for a date, but just doesn't show the item for id 5. But it still shows the dates that an id 5 existed in.

Comment: @Veo: Please could you clarify with some example data?  As shown in the sqlfiddle, only `(user_id, stamp)` pairs for which there is no `item_id=5` are returned.

Comment: Will do - i'm in the process of putting in some test data now into that fiddle.

Comment: Ok - I think the reason it didn't work is because the stamp is a datetime, not just a date. My apologies I was trying to simplify the data - too much I guess. The actual ID that i'm looking for is 12. Here's the fiddle. Also - as a long time visitor, but first time poster - you guys are fantastic!! and the fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91e54/1

Comment: @Veo: Just replace the two references to `stamp` in my answer above with `DATE(stamp)`.  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91e54/2/0).